# How does the Community bot flag duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

What algorithm does the [Community bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) use to flag duplicate questions?

I think our human beings, when understand the algorithm being used, can execute the same algorithm by ourselves before asking questions. This can help reduce management cost.

Comment: ...and if you agree with me, you have a chance to see the feature in action.